# P4 tutorials/basic make run : No module named 'p4'

Tags: p4-lang

environment: VMware,
Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.
Python 2.7.17

I am a new beginner with P4, so I try to run the P4 tutorials/basic.
I try to make run, and the error as following:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "../../utils/run_exercise.py", line 28, in 
> import p4runtime_lib.simple_controller
> File "/home/john/p4tools/tutorials/utils/p4runtime_lib/simple_controller.py", line 22, in 
> from p4.config.v1 import p4info_pb2
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'p4'

How should I do? Where is p4 module? If it is miss, how can I install?

Comment: Why are you using Python 2.7?  Python 2 has been a "dead language" for a while, and there's a prebuilt P4Python module for Python 3.

Comment: On closer inspection, this seems to be about the P4 language, not Perforce...

Comment: Did you used vagrant to setup the p4 envrionment?